# Getting "F/vendor.qti.esepowermanager" error on logcat continuously when debugging a Flutter app on a real device

Tags: android, flutter, android-debugging

I'm new to Flutter and overall Android development. When I run the virtual device from Android Studio, I don't get any errors. However, when I connect my device running on a custom ROM to a laptop (USB debugging enabled and installed Google USB driver from Android Studio), I get the following errors continuously:

```
$ flutter run

Launching lib\main.dart on Mi MIX 3 5G in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...      
F/GPQeSE-HAL(31453): Error while registering secure_element V1.2 service: -2147483648
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...      
F/vendor.qti.esepowermanager@1.1-service(31452): Error while registering eSE power manager service: -2147483648
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...      
F/vendor.qti.esepowermanager@1.0-service(31451): Error while registering eSE power manager service: -2147483648
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...      
F/vendor.qti.esepowermanager@1.1-service(31489): Error while registering eSE power manager service: -2147483648
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...      
F/GPQeSE-HAL(31490): Error while registering secure_element V1.2 service: -2147483648
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...      
F/vendor.qti.esepowermanager@1.0-service(31488): Error while registering eSE power manager service: -2147483648
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...      
F/GPQeSE-HAL(31518): Error while registering secure_element V1.2 service: -2147483648
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...      
F/vendor.qti.esepowermanager@1.1-service(31517): Error while registering eSE power manager service: -2147483648
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...      
F/vendor.qti.esepowermanager@1.0-service(31516): Error while registering eSE power manager service: -2147483648
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...      

Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done 15.0s

√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.

F/GPQeSE-HAL(31689): Error while registering secure_element V1.2 service: -2147483648
F/vendor.qti.esepowermanager@1.0-service(31686): Error while registering eSE power manager service: -2147483648
F/vendor.qti.esepowermanager@1.1-service(31687): Error while registering eSE power manager service: -2147483648

Syncing files to device Mi MIX 3 5G... 72ms

Flutter run key commands.
r Hot reload.
R Hot restart.
h Repeat this help message.
d Detach (terminate "flutter run" but leave application running).
c Clear the screen
q Quit (terminate the application on the device).

Running with sound null safety

An Observatory debugger and profiler on Mi MIX 3 5G is available at: http://127.0.0.1:54763/6oO2jX9xZzI=/
Activating Dart DevTools...
F/vendor.qti.esepowermanager@1.1-service(31758): Error while registering eSE power manager service: -2147483648
Activating Dart DevTools...
F/GPQeSE-HAL(31759): Error while registering secure_element V1.2 service: -2147483648
Activating Dart DevTools...
F/vendor.qti.esepowermanager@1.0-service(31757): Error while registering eSE power manager service: -2147483648
Activating Dart DevTools... 2,677ms
The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on Mi MIX 3 5G is available at: http://127.0.0.1:9101?uri=http%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A54763%2F6oO2jX9xZzI%3D%2F
F/GPQeSE-HAL(31785): Error while registering secure_element V1.2 service: -2147483648
```

Although I can run the default Flutter app on my Android device, for now, I'm worried it will give me more headaches in the future and it's annoying.

Comment: What OS are you using for your development? A quick google leds me to believe that those error messages are from Lineage OS

Comment: I'm on pixel experience. https://download.pixelexperience.org/andromeda ; this is link to rom page. I'm using android 11 plus edition.

Comment: They are probably using LineageOS as their base. I cannot find any other reference for those errors, so i would say that those are probably not related to flutter and you probably are fine. If you are running into problems i would suggest opening a issue in the flutter repository...maybe they know more about this then.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the OS you are using for running the app on the mobile device. Normally, if you keep USB Debugging and the developer mode on in the mobile device, you won't get any further issues. Just make sure that all the required developer options are toggled on. Generally, keep a good connection both with the mobile and the internet to avoid errors due to lag in the service.
For more info, you can run command for flutter doctor on you command prompt. If it shows a tick in front of mobile connection, you are ready to go.

Answer (score 0):

I have contacted the developer of the ROM, Nicholas Magill, and turns out it is not a huge problem, just log spam. According to him, `esepowermanager` is part of the NQ NFC stack which was disabled and replaced with the AOSP NFC stack.

In order to get rid of the log spam, you can delete `/vendor/bin/hw/vendor.qti.esepowermanager@1.0-service` and `/vendor/bin/hw/vendor.qti.esepowermanager@1.1-service` in recovery mode (this is probably device special).

I fixed it by flashing a script that he gave me. So it's not a huge problem but could be annoying and precious error messages could be lost in them.

Answer (score 0):

this was a top hit for me for

Unable to create service vendor.qti.data.txpwradmin.StxPwrService

this crash was happening continuously for me after a bad os upgrade, I had to factory reset.